# Uncaught ReferenceError: geolib is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I just downloaded geolib with NPM with --save and when I tried to use it I received:

Uncaught ReferenceError: geolib is not defined

in the JS console. After that I added a script to pointed at the .js file in the proper director on my index.html file.  I also checked in my package.json and it is there as a dependency. Finally, I copy and pasted a version into my bower_components folder. What else do I need to do to get my project actively recognizing it?

The full error as requested:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: geolib is not definedoffer.controller.js:186 $scope.consumerMatch.userTableQuery.get.success.cMatch.find.success.mMatch.find.successparse.js:4022 (anonymous function)parse.js:3895 _.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackparse.js:3839 (anonymous function)parse.js:95 _.each._.forEachparse.js:3838 _.extend.resolveparse.js:3905 _.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackparse.js:3839 (anonymous function)parse.js:95 _.each._.forEachparse.js:3838 _.extend.resolveparse.js:3905 _.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackparse.js:3839 (anonymous function)parse.js:95 _.each._.forEachparse.js:3838 _.extend.resolveparse.js:3900 (anonymous function)parse.js:3895 _.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackparse.js:3957 (anonymous function)parse.js:3940 _.extend.then.runLaterparse.js:3956 _.extend.thenparse.js:3899 _.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackparse.js:3839 (anonymous function)parse.js:95 _.each._.forEachparse.js:3838 _.extend.resolveparse.js:1536 Parse._ajax.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: Please include the full error and the code where the error occurs.

Comment: I don't think there is more to it than what's posted above. I'm just kind of new to node and I'm not really sure what's involved with the different elements to either 'require', post in the index or add to app.js module or why/whether something goes in node_modules or bower_components.  Are there rules for this?

Comment: Please post your code. From what you have posted above it looks like you have posted the error only

Comment: @Gardezi - thanks for chiming in on this. It has been almost two years however. I eventually got it working and I think the missing component was importing geolib into the angular project.

Comment: @rashadb then I would suggest that you should either post the answer so that if anybody has the same problem as yours, he can get help from your post.

Comment: @Gardezi I absolutely agree with you and in most cases I have. Unfortunately for some reason I failed to do so over a year ago. Is this a problem you're currently having? If so I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: @rashadb no no I'm not facing any problem. I was saying it because somebody out there might face this problem and maybe your solution may help him